# How can I make a function that loops over a list and takes which data member to access as input parameter

Tags: c#, generalization

I have a datatype PlayerStats which contains a lot of different data members. I want to calculate a score which is different for each data member (the case below looks at statistics.nrOfGoals).

```
private double getScore()
{
    double strength = 0;
    foreach (PlayerStats statistics in this.statistics)
    {
        double dateDiff = Math.Abs(nowDate.Subtract(statistics.date).Days / (365.25 / 12));
        dateDiff = Math.Pow(dateDiff, Form1.historyFactor);

        strength += (statistics.nrOfGoals * ValueTable.PointsPerGoals   ) / dateDiff;
    }

    return strength;
}
```

How can I make this function general and accept which datamember to look at instead of creating a lot of similar looking functions?

Something like

```
private double getScore(Type type, Type type2)
{
    double strength = 0;
    foreach (PlayerStats statistics in this.statistics)
    {
        double dateDiff = Math.Abs(nowDate.Subtract(statistics.date).Days / (365.25 / 12));
        dateDiff = Math.Pow(dateDiff, Form1.historyFactor);

        strength += (statistics.type * ValueTable.type2) / dateDiff;
    }

    return strength;
}
```

Comment: Using a memberexpression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a function as a parameter with signature `PlayerStats -> Double`:

```
private double getScore(Func<PlayerStats,double> type, double type2)
{
    double strength = 0;
    foreach (PlayerStats statistics in this.statistics)
    {
        double dateDiff = Math.Abs(nowDate.Subtract(statistics.date).Days / (365.25 / 12));
        dateDiff = Math.Pow(dateDiff, Form1.historyFactor);

        strength += (type(statistics) * type2) / dateDiff;
    }

    return strength;
}
```

And then call it with:

```
getScore(x => x.nrOfGoals,ValueTable.PointsPerGoals);
```

`x => x.nrOfGoals` is a [*lambda-expression*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that defines some kind of function that (in this case) takes as input a `PlayerStats` instance and returns a `double`.

In the code, you can then see `type` as a "function"/"method" and call it with `type(y)` (with `y` a `PlayerStats` instance).

Comment: @Oday: is there a specific reason to make `type2` a function as well?

Comment: In the first function, the second operand  is  ValueTable.PointsPerGoals. In the second function, the second operand is ValueTable.type2. I can infer that both multiplication operands can be changed.

Comment: @Oday: no: the first function takes only one parameter: the `PlayerStats`, the `double` in the signature is the type of the result. A `Func<T>` is probably only useful if the result can change (for instance a random number generator). Here it is reasonable to assume the weight will remain fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You could put the property names as string parameters and look up properties by name using reflection.

Comment: That will work, but it is more inefficient and less safe: using lambda-expressions, the compiler can check whether the aspect actually exists. Whereas reflection uses strings. If at one point you rename a property it will break. I think one better doesn't use reflection unless it is absolutely useful..

Comment: I agree, but giving up type safety gives you maximum flexibility in naming any existing or future property to use in the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `Func<PlayerStats, double>` to your function, like:

```
private double getScore(Func<PlayerStats, double> evaluator)
{
    double strength = 0;
    foreach (PlayerStats statistics in this.statistics)
    {
        double dateDiff = Math.Abs(nowDate.Subtract(statistics.date).Days / (365.25 / 12));
        dateDiff = Math.Pow(dateDiff, Form1.historyFactor);

        strength += evaluator(statistics) / dateDiff;
    }

    return strength;
}
```

And then call it like (in your shown case)

```
getScore(x => x.nrOfGoals * ValueTable.PointsPerGoals);
```

Comment: The `ValueTable` probably gives, statistic-dependent weights?

Comment: @CommuSoft Maybe, but for me it is more likely looks like some constant (just based on its name).